# Netezza while loop syntax

Tags: netezza

I want to make a statement in netezza so that it waits until a statement is correct before proceeding. Any help would be appreciated - something similar to the below

```
WHILE (
select count(*) EVENT_DESCRIPTION from TEST_DA_CONTROL.CTRL.C_DBA_MAINTENANCE_AUDIT
    where EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'STARTED' and DATETIME_LOGGED > (select add_months(current_date,0))) = 0
LOOP
wait 5
end loop;
```

but I don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to assign that output to a variable. I seem to recall that getting data out of an `execute immediate` is a little arduous in nzplsql, but there are convenient variables already available for you to use. Here I'll use `ROW_COUNT`.

```
declare 
  event_descriptions int;
  sql varchar;

begin  
  event_descriptions := 1;
  while event_descriptions > 0 loop
    --Actual work
    sql := '
      select * EVENT_DESCRIPTION from TEST_DA_CONTROL.CTRL.C_DBA_MAINTENANCE_AUDIT
      where EVENT_DESCRIPTION = ''STARTED'' and DATETIME_LOGGED > (select add_months(current_date,0))) = 0;';
    execute immediate sql;
    event_descriptions := ROW_COUNT;
  end loop;
end;
```